# Javascript computing permutations - why is my code returning unwanted solution when I don't make a copy of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is code for a function that returns all permutations of a given array.

```
function getAllPerms(s) {
  var perms = [];
  if (s.length === 1) {
    perms.push(s);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            var sub = s.slice(0);
            sub.splice(i, 1);
            var sp = getAllPerms(sub);
            for (var o = 0; o < sp.length; o++) {
                sp[o].unshift(s[i]);
                perms.push(sp[o]);
            }
        }
    }
    return perms;
  }
  console.log(getAllPerms([1,2]));  // result is [[1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

however if i don't make a copy of the array and splice the original array I don't get the same output, and I have been racking my brain to understand why?  To me, it seems as though it should work either way.  Below is the code with changes to the original array.

```
function getAllPerms(s) {
    var perms = [];
    var len = s.length
    if (s.length === 1) {
        perms.push(s);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var digit = s[i];
            s.splice(i, 1);
            var sp = getAllPerms(s);
            for (var o = 0; o < sp.length; o++) {
                sp[o].unshift(digit);
                perms.push(sp[o]);
            }
        }
    }
    return perms;
}
console.log(getAllPerms([1,2])); // result is [[2, 1], [2, 1]]
```

For the first set of code I get the correct result,[[1, 2], [2, 1]], but for the second bit of code I get something strange, [[2, 1], [2, 1]].  Cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on.

Comment: Where is the return of `splice`?

Comment: Could it be that `len` is constant but `s.length` changes with `push`?

Comment: splice will modify the original array...  len needs to be constant each recursive call to getAllPerms...  Derek Peirce simplified the issue below.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code that changes the original array, you're actually modifying the input array `s`to be first `[1,2]` then `[2,1]`, and your return array is just the original array `s` multiple times, so modifying `s` to become the second element also modifies it as the first element.

You can see the effect more simply by running the following:

```
var x = [1,2]
var p = []
p.push(x)
x[0] = 2
x[1] = 1
p.push(x)
```

Observe how `x` and `p` change after each line.

Comment: I see, each time you are pushing X its just a reference to the array, so as X, the original array, changes so does each instance where it was pushed onto P...   thanks!